# MySql 'Order by Date' Question

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

Im pulling data from a MySql data table.  I'm pulling from a row called 'PubDate' (meaning Published date).  This format is in Date format, not DateTime.  When I execute the query

```
Select * from Articles order by pubDate ASC
```

Its ordered by date as so:

1.09/18/09
2.09/18/09
3.09/19/09
4.09/20/09

If possible I would like to be able to get the most recent date first by using the 'ASC' value for direction due to my current code logic.  I've already tried

```
Select * from Article order by Cast(pubdate as datetime) ASC
```

but didn't change the output.  I CAN do DESC (descending order) if I must...but its not preferable.

Comment: ASC will have the oldest date at the top; DESC will have the most recent date at the top..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> the most recent date first

For this you must use `DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your newest articles to be first use `DESC`. default is `ASC` so there is no point in explicitely adding it